# Arreglo dentro de un objeto con Javascript

Tags: javascript

explico el problema cada mes tiene tres posibles estados (bueno,malo y regular) y se debe conocer el estado de cada mes dado un arreglo de años en especifico en este caso para el año 2016 y 2017.

Estos son mis avances

```js
var status_state = {},meses_states={},anios_state={},datos_state=[];
var years=[2016,2017];
var months=["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"];
var states=["Bueno","Malo","Regular"];
for (var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
  var year=years[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < months.length; j++) {
    var month=months[j];
    for (var k = 0; k < states.length; k++) {
      var state=states[k];
      status_state.bueno=Math.random();
      status_state.malo=Math.random();
      status_state.regular=Math.random();
    }
    meses_states.month=status_state; 
  }
  anios_state.year=meses_states;
}
datos_state.push({anos: anios_state});
console.log("Informacion Almacenada");
console.log(datos_state);
```

agregue un random para simular datos, pero como ven no me muestra los años ni meses

Comment: Sería bueno que edites tu pregunta e indiques cuál debería ser la estructura final de tu objeto (como resultado esperado).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siempre estas usando los mismos objetos y los sobreescribes una y otra vez, necesitas agregarle arreglos a tus objetos para ir guardando cada mes y cada año

```js
var status_state = {},meses_states={},anios_state={},datos_state=[];
var years=[2016,2017];
var months=["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"];
var states=["Bueno","Malo","Regular"];
for (var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
  var year=years[i];
  anios_state={};//Creas un objeto nuevo
  anios_state.year = year;
  anios_state.yearMonths = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < months.length; j++) {
    var month=months[j];
    for (var k = 0; k < states.length; k++) {
      var state=states[k];
      status_state = {};//Creas un objeto nuevo
      status_state.bueno=Math.random();
      status_state.malo=Math.random();
      status_state.regular=Math.random();
    }
    meses_states = {};//Creas un objeto nuevo
    meses_states.month=month;
    meses_states.monthStatus=status_state;
    anios_state.yearMonths.push(meses_states); 
  }  
  datos_state.push({anos: anios_state});
}
console.log("Informacion Almacenada");
console.log(datos_state);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, no domino esa parte...saludos